# Given that i have loop my worksheets to produce some data , how to sort these data in a more organised manner?

Tags: excel, vba

So how my program works is that it will loop through all these worksheets to find invalid/fail data and after that the final result will be paste starting from row 1 column A. The count/countini/countinv represents the number of rel/initial/invalid fails respectively. Lets just assume i have 4 worksheets namely "devicea","deviceb","devicec" and "deviced" to loop on to get the number of rel/initial/invalid fails data (the numbers shown on the extreme left of column A) in each worksheet. How can i extract the worksheet name that lies in the same cell as the count's name like example if count's name is "rel"(at column A row5), how do i extract the name of the worksheet device d not just for my case but for all cases and organise them like the one i shown in after portion of the picture?

```
If Count >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Count & " REL Failures in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"

If countini >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countini & " Initial Failures in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"
end if

If countinv >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countinv & " Invalid Data points in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"
endif
```

' ^ the above chunk of lines used to generate output at column A. Just need to know the variables; Count = no of rel failures, countini = no of initial failures, countinv = no of invalid data points. Well the below codes are the one that i am concern and need help for it..

```
Dim lastrow1 As Long

lastrow1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Row = 2 To lastrow1

mytext1 = Count & Sheets(1).Range("A" & Row).Value
' for the case of rel fails

If mytext1(2) = "rel" Then

'get the worksheetname that lies the same cell as "REL"
mytext1(4)=
```

[image]

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you need. Are you trying to make the table on the right out of the text on the left? If so, instead of creating the string of text first and then make a table, try making the table at the same time since you already have all the data at that time, I think?

Comment: @czeskleba yeah, im trying to make the table on the right out of the text from left

Comment: @czeskleba what do you mean by making a table at the same time?

Comment: You start the code with `If Count >= 1 Then`. What that `Count` is? Should we do not look to your code and only try to extract what you need from the table of the left side?

Comment: The first code you quoted makes the text on the left, correct? Just make it also make the table at that time. Imma post an answer, to show what I mean. I just noticed, your first code is missing an endif too

Comment: I cannot also understand why `deviced` appears twice in your `AFTER` design and the `REL failures` are not counted on the second row, second column... Is there what you wanted, or you just missed it?

Comment: @Faneduru the count here refers to the no of reliability failures as mentioned above.  Because the left side of my data may vary, like it may not be fixed at just 5 data , it can be 6 or more and i dunno how to deal with this kind of scenario. Ultimately yes, i wan to extract what i need from left side even when data varies?

Comment: @Faneduru actually that is what i wanted but i afraid that is too much to ask thats why i start with just lining up data in rows regardless of duplicates...

Comment: But, this "extraction" don't it mean to have on the AFTER first column your unique devices, and fill in the next column according to each category values?

Comment: @czeskeba alright,thanks alot of mate

Comment: @faneduru yeah if u say it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant in my comment, just create the table at the same time as the text on the left. I assume Count/countini/countinv are not empty but instead 0? If not, you need to do an if statement or something.

```
If Count >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Count & " REL Failures in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"
'You sure, you dont need an end if here?

If countini >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countini & " Initial Failures in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"
end if

If countinv >= 1 Then
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countinv & " Invalid Data points in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " !"
endif

'This creates the table
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Name

'edited in after your comment:
If Count Like "" Then Count = 0
If countini Like "" Then countini = 0
If countinv Like "" Then countinv = 0

Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Count
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countini
Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = countinv
```

Comment: ah i get your idea....anyways how do you make the cells that are empty at the same row = 0? Like the one shown in device a row...

Comment: i mean right now your suggestion will not consider empty cells as zero?

Comment: Is Count and countini empty when its not 1 or greater?

Comment: same goes for countinv too...when its not 1 or greater

Comment: You used lots of if statements so I used that style too. I edited the answer.